# gcc changing output depending on whether address is observed or not

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to make a program that prints "eggy weggy." by storing the values of the characters in 3 variables (`x`, `y` and `z`). I've tried adding a `for` loop to print this several times, but this is where the weirdness begins. If I put `printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", &x, &y, &z, &i);` anywhere in the code, the output is as desired. But if I exclude this, the program just prints "eggy" multiple times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned x = 2036819813; //sequence of 'y', 'g', 'g', 'e'
    unsigned y = 1734702880; //sequence of 'g', 'e', 'w', ' '
    unsigned z = 3045735; //sequence of '\0', '.', 'y', 'g'
    char* ptr = (char*)&x;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
    }
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", &x, &y, &z, &i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
eggy weggy.
0x7ffc2844d000
0x7ffc2844d004
0x7ffc2844d008
0x7ffc2844d00c
```

Now without the `printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", &x, &y, &z, &i);`

Output:

```c
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
eggy
```

Also, if I don't do this in a loop, it prints out "eggy weggy." correctly. This just seems bizarre to me. I didn't know that the state of variables can be determined by whether or not their value is observed. Is this a bug? Is it an optimization thing? Any info is appreciated :)

Note: I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 with the arguments `-O0 -std=c89 -Wall` (and I'm not running this on a quantum computer)

Edit: The code runs as expected when I compile it in clang, but I've had to switch out the order of declaration for `x` and `z`, since clang puts the newer variables in lower memory addresses that the older variables, unlike gcc which puts them in higher addresses.

Comment: Since the code without `printf` does not explicity use `y` and `z`, and the code relies on undefined behaviour anyway, then perhaps `y` and `z` have been optimized out.

Comment: "I didn't know that the state of variables can be determined by whether or not their value is observed." That's what happens when you run your programs in a quantum computer

Comment: @WeatherVane this might be the case, but if i remove `i` and the `for` loop and don't use the `printf`, it still works fine

Comment: Just write proper code and don't struggle to understand why improper code might, or might not, work.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-O0`?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Or at least, if you want to understand what's going on at the lower level of the machine, inspect things at that level: read the assembly code, dump memory with a debugger, etc.  Don't try to get this information filtered through the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't know that the state of variables can be determined by whether or not their value is observed.

The C standard ultimately defines programs only in terms of their observable behavior, which is, per C 2018 5.1.2.3 6:

> Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input.

So, if an object is never used, the optimizer in the compiler may remove it from the program completely, because the observable behavior of the program is the same whether the object is removed or not.

If the address of an object is printed, that causes output that is observable behavior, and the compiler must ensure the addresses printed match the memory model the C standard describes. The optimizer does not actually have to keep these objects in memory, but it has to provide nominal reservations for their memory, so that there are assigned addresses it can print.

These requirements caused differences in your two versions of the program, and those differences happened to cause the changes you observed when you used `ptr` outside of the ways defined by the C standard. Notably, when it is passed to `printf` for a `%s` conversion, it should point to the first character of a null-terminated sequence of characters. Further, since it is a pointer to `x`, that sequence should not extend beyond `x`. Since both of those requirements are violated, the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. It may have shown you data “beyond” `x` in these trials, but that is not something you should rely on. And the data that was “beyond” `x` happened to depend on the optimizations described above or similar effects.